# Downloading an attachment from Teams across a Bot Nodejs

Tags: botframework

I'm facing the following error when I try to get the attachment in Microsoft Teams with Bot Builder v4:

{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

everything works fine with the version 3, as far as I know in Teams is necessary a token in order get the binary array of the file.
In the v3 I'm able to get the jwt token in this way:
connector.getAccessToken.bind(connector)

and then I use it in the header of the GET request =>

```
headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
         }
```

In the v4:
context.adapter.getUserToken(step.context, CONNECTION_SETTING_NAME);

is there another way to get a valid token in the v4?

Answer (score 0):

To get the token just call the prompt again. You can find the [auth sample here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication/bot.js) for node.  The sample happens to use a waterfall dialog, which may not be needed in  your case

```
let prompt = await step.prompt(OAUTH_PROMPT);
```

If the token is valid and not expired you can get the token like below, if the token is not valid or the user does not have a token they will be prompted to log in.  Otherwise the token will be in the prompt result.

```
var tokenResponse = prompt.result;
if (tokenResponse != null) {
    await step.context.sendActivity(`Here is your token: ${ tokenResponse.token }`);
}
```

These comments from the sample should help explain

```
// Call the prompt again because we need the token. The reasons for this are:
// 1. If the user is already logged in we do not need to store the token locally in the bot and worry
// about refreshing it. We can always just call the prompt again to get the token.
// 2. We never know how long it will take a user to respond. By the time the
// user responds the token may have expired. The user would then be prompted to login again.
//
// There is no reason to store the token locally in the bot because we can always just call
// the OAuth prompt to get the token or get a new token if needed.
```

Comment: I tried also this way without any success, the token is correctly added into the headers but for some reason the request fails:
{"message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}

Comment: could you provide some more code so I can try to repro and get you the the correct answer then?

Answer (score 0):

these are the steps

```
 /**
 * WaterfallDialogStep to process the user's picture.
 * @param {WaterfallStepContext} step WaterfallStepContext
 */
async processPhotoStep(step) {
    await this.writeLogInTheStorage('Start downloading picture....');
    await this.handleIncomingAttachment(step);
    return await step.endDialog();
};
/**
 * responds to the user with information about the saved attachment or an error.
 * @param {Object} turnContext 
 */
async handleIncomingAttachment(step) {
    // Prepare Promises to download each attachment and then execute each Promise.
    const attachment = step.context.activity.attachments[0];
    const tokenIsRequired = await this.checkRequiresToken(step.context);
    const dc = await this.dialogs.createContext(step.context);
    const token = await dc.beginDialog(LOGIN_PROMPT); //await step.context.adapter.getUserToken(step.context, CONNECTION_SETTING_NAME);
    let file = undefined;
    if (tokenIsRequired) {
        file = await this.downloadAttachment(token.result.token, attachment.contentUrl);
    }
    else {
        file = await requestX(attachment.contentUrl);
    }
    await OAuthHelpers.postPhoto(step.context, token.result, file);
}

async downloadAttachment(token, url) {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
            }
        }, async function (err, response, body) {
            const result = body

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                //await this.writeLogInTheStorage('err 1 : ' + err);
                reject(err);
            } else if (result.error) {
                console.log(result.error);
                //await this.writeLogInTheStorage('err 2 : ' + err);
                reject(result.error.message);
            } else {
                // The value of the body will be an array.
                console.log(result);
                //await this.writeLogInTheStorage('success : ' + result);
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
    return p;
}
```